# Translate postgres crosstab query to TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following thing I want to achieve:

A DB that stores translations in different languages. With a single query get all strings in the desired language and if that translation doesn't exist use the second best language as fallback etc. For each language the fallbacks may differ (e.g. FR-DE-EN vs. DE-EN-FR).

I've implemented it with pgsql via a crosstab query and wanted to translate this to SQL Server but got kind of stuck there. I think that [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) would be the language feature to achieve my desired outcome but haven't yet figured out how to use it properly.

MWE definitions and testdata:

```
-- load tablefunc extension for crosstab
drop extension if exists tablefunc;
create extension tablefunc;
-- crosstab only allows single column - define int and varchar tuples for this purpose
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS intT; CREATE TYPE intT AS  (module int, id int );
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS strT; CREATE TYPE strT AS (lang varchar, txt varchar);

drop table if exists texts;
drop table if exists langs;

create table texts
(   module int not null
,   id int not null
,   lang varchar not null
,   txt varchar not null);

create table langs -- for each language (first) store up to 3 languages (lang) and their priority (lower = would be used first)
(   first varchar not null
,   lang varchar not null
,   priority int not null);

insert into texts (module, id, lang, txt) values
    (0,0,'def','HelloDEF'),
    (0,1,'def','WorldDEF'),
    (0,0,'en','Hello'),
    (0,1,'en','World'),
    (0,0,'de','Hallo'),
    (0,1,'de','Welt'),
    (0,0,'jp','Konnichiwa'),
    (0,1,'fr','Monde'),
    (1,0,'def','Switzerland'),
    (1,0,'de','Schweiz'),
    (1,0,'fr','Suisse'),
    (1,0,'jp','Suisu');

insert into langs (first, lang, priority) values
    ('jp','jp',0),
    ('jp','en',1),
    ('jp','def',2),
    ('en','en',0),
    ('en','def',1),
    ('en','def',2),
    ('de','de',0),
    ('de','en',1),
    ('de','def',2),
    ('fr','fr',0),
    ('fr','de',1),
    ('fr','def',2);
```

Query (pgsql):

```
select (mod_id).*, (coalesce(a,b,c)).* -- unpack tuple types here to get nice table
from crosstab($$
    select (module,id) as mod_id, priority, (lang,txt) as lang_txt
    from texts
    join langs using (lang)
    where first = 'fr' --! language goes here
    and module = 0 --! module integer goes here
    order by id, priority asc
$$,$$
    select generate_series(0,2) -- always return 0,1,2 here.
$$) as ct (mod_id intT, a strT, b strT, c strT);
```

Output:

```
 module | id | lang |  txt
--------+----+------+-------
      0 |  0 | de   | Hallo
      0 |  1 | fr   | Monde
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, this result can be achieved with standard SQL without the need for pivoting the data. Simple `ROW_NUMBER()` should be enough. The query below will work in SQL Server and Postgres.

**Sample data**

```
create table #texts
(   module int not null
,   id int not null
,   lang varchar(50) not null
,   txt varchar(50) not null);

create table #langs -- for each language (first) store up to 3 languages (lang) and their priority (lower = would be used first)
(   first varchar(50) not null
,   lang varchar(50) not null
,   priority int not null);

insert into #texts (module, id, lang, txt) values
    (0,0,'def','HelloDEF'),
    (0,1,'def','WorldDEF'),
    (0,0,'en','Hello'),
    (0,1,'en','World'),
    (0,0,'de','Hallo'),
    (0,1,'de','Welt'),
    (0,0,'jp','Konnichiwa'),
    (0,1,'fr','Monde'),
    (1,0,'def','Switzerland'),
    (1,0,'de','Schweiz'),
    (1,0,'fr','Suisse'),
    (1,0,'jp','Suisu');

insert into #langs (first, lang, priority) values
    ('jp','jp',0),
    ('jp','en',1),
    ('jp','def',2),
    ('en','en',0),
    ('en','def',1),
    ('en','def',2),
    ('de','de',0),
    ('de','en',1),
    ('de','def',2),
    ('fr','fr',0),
    ('fr','de',1),
    ('fr','def',2);
```

**Query**

I have taken your inner query and added a `ROW_NUMBER` there. It is clear that we simply need to pick only the row with the highest `priority` for each `id` (that's why there is `PARTITION BY id` and `ORDER BY priority` in the `ROW_NUMBER` definition). If you want results for several `module`s at once, not just for one specific module, then add `module` to `PARTITION BY` clause.

```
SELECT
    #texts.module
    ,#texts.id
    ,#langs.priority
    ,#langs.lang
    ,#texts.txt
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #texts.id ORDER BY #langs.priority) AS rn
FROM
    #texts
    INNER JOIN #langs ON #langs.lang = #texts.lang
WHERE
    #langs.first = 'fr' --! language goes here
    AND #texts.module = 0 --! module integer goes here
ORDER BY
    #texts.id, #langs.priority asc
;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+----+----------+------+----------+----+
| module | id | priority | lang |   txt    | rn |
+--------+----+----------+------+----------+----+
|      0 |  0 |        1 | de   | Hallo    |  1 |
|      0 |  0 |        2 | def  | HelloDEF |  2 |
|      0 |  1 |        0 | fr   | Monde    |  1 |
|      0 |  1 |        1 | de   | Welt     |  2 |
|      0 |  1 |        2 | def  | WorldDEF |  3 |
+--------+----+----------+------+----------+----+
```

**Final Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        #texts.module
        ,#texts.id
        ,#langs.priority
        ,#langs.lang
        ,#texts.txt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY #texts.id ORDER BY #langs.priority) AS rn
    FROM
        #texts
        INNER JOIN #langs ON #langs.lang = #texts.lang
    WHERE
        #langs.first = 'fr' --! language goes here
        AND #texts.module = 0 --! module integer goes here
)
SELECT
    module
    ,id
    ,lang
    ,txt
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY
    id
;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+----+------+-------+
| module | id | lang |  txt  |
+--------+----+------+-------+
|      0 |  0 | de   | Hallo |
|      0 |  1 | fr   | Monde |
+--------+----+------+-------+
```

**Clean up**

```
drop table #texts;
drop table #langs;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Way more elegant this way.